# How to put select statement returned into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this stored procedure,

```
Create procedure [dbo].[Craping_GetFruitCrapedOrNot]
(
    @FruitID int,
    @CrateID int,
    @FruitName varchar(100)
)
AS
  SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
  (
     SELECT     Craping.CRAPED
     FROM         Fruits 
          INNER JOIN Craping 
          ON Fruits.ID = Craping.FruitID
     WHERE     
         (Fruits.FruitTable = @FruitName) 
         AND (Craping.FruitID = @FruitID) 
         AND (Craping.CrateID = @CrateID)
  ) 
  THEN 'False'
  ELSE 'True'
  END AS FruitNotCraped
GO
```

Now    if exists then instead of returning false  `THEN 'False'` I want to return whatever returned from select statement, not sure how though?

```
Then return SELECT     Craping.CRAPED
         FROM         Fruits 
              INNER JOIN Craping 
              ON Fruits.ID = Craping.FruitID
         WHERE     
             (Fruits.FruitTable = @FruitName) 
             AND (Craping.FruitID = @FruitID) 
             AND (Craping.CrateID = @CrateID)
```

Comment: Why not just return the results from the query?  You'll get no rows if nothing exists.  And, perhaps you really want a user defined function rather than a stored procedure.

Comment: @GordonLinoff because it's been used in typed dataset which I cannot touch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 DECLARE @Craped NVARCHAR(50)

 SELECT     @Craped = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), Craping.CRAPED)
 FROM         Fruits 
      INNER JOIN Craping 
      ON Fruits.ID = Craping.FruitID
 WHERE     
     (Fruits.FruitTable = @FruitName) 
     AND (Craping.FruitID = @FruitID) 
     AND (Craping.CrateID = @CrateID)

 SELECT CASE
            WHEN @@ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN 'True'
            ELSE @Craped
        END AS [FruitNotCraped]
```

**Notes:**

- I tested for @@ROWCOUNT instead of @Craped IS NULL just in case it is possible that the Craping.CRAPED field could be NULL as a valid value.

Comment: @CustomizedName: I had already updated my answer to include a note that addresses this. I can update again to integrate this info, though.

Comment: Thank You, however i am getting exception - Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'True' to data type int.  when no record exists otherwise works fine

Comment: @CustomizedName: Actually, I just changed the answer to go the other way to keep in line with the original return type expectation. I had previously updated my answer too hastily and didn't catch that all I needed was the CONVERT given the new info on the datatype. However, either minor change is valid depending on what return type you prefer.